# Was scrape worth changing to s****e here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just stumbled over this change (second revision):

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17225363/2

and I'm wondering what the sense of it could be because I never thought that scrape is an offending term.

(I'm not concerned about removing the extract tag here)

Comment: Woah... since when did "scrape" become offensive?

Comment: It’s not an offensive term. It does, however, contain “crap”. Michael Myers… what horribly restrictive censoring extension are you using? D:

Comment: Whoah, whoah, whoah... let's watch the language in the title, there could be minors around.

Comment: @minitechη I find that censoring extension to be offensive. :P

Comment: Yeah, this is just what a dirty Scraper would say. You're all a bunch of scraping scrapers.

Comment: Just be lucky it wasn't "damn"

Comment: That's clbuttic!

Comment: [clbuttic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem#News_articles_damaged)

Comment: ever heard of the city named "s****horpe"? Oh, sorry, my corporate filter is on.

Comment: Looks like @MichaelMyers was accepted into the Jeff Atwood school of newspeak.

Comment: Well, it only took me a year and five months to discover this question (which I'm a little miffed about - one's first Meta callout should be an exciting occasion!). [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185408/was-scrape-worth-changing-to-se-here/185413#comment567898_185413) has the best guess; this was indeed completely unintentional on my part.